# t-sql: create and add several namespaces to xml

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm kinda new working with xml in sql and have to build a xml like this [My Xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWGH5.png)
and replace with correct values where (...) appears.

Replacement is not my problem, otherwise creating the several namespaces that appears on the previous image is.

```sql
DECLARE @XML XML

SET @XML = (SELECT   
              (SELECT 
                     (SELECT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xmlexcc14n#' "@Algorithm"
                        FOR XML PATH('CanonicalizationMethod'), TYPE),
                     (SELECT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsigmore#rsasha256' "@Algorithm"
                        FOR XML PATH('SignatureMethod'), TYPE),
                     (SELECT '#FATCA' "@URI",
                             (SELECT 
                                     (SELECT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xmlexcc14n#' "@Algorithm"
                                       FOR XML PATH('Transform'), TYPE)
                                 FOR XML PATH('Transforms'), TYPE),
                             (SELECT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256' "@Algorithm"
                                 FOR XML PATH('DigestMethod'), TYPE),
                             (SELECT ''
                                 FOR XML PATH('DigestValue'), TYPE)
                         FOR XML PATH('Reference'), TYPE)                            
                 FOR XML PATH('SignedInfo'), TYPE),
              (SELECT ''
                 FOR XML PATH('SignatureValue'), TYPE),
              (SELECT
                     (SELECT
                            (SELECT ''
                               FOR XML PATH('X509SubjectName'), TYPE),
                            (SELECT ''
                               FOR XML PATH('X509Certificate'), TYPE)
                        FOR XML PATH('X509Data'), TYPE)
                 FOR XML PATH('KeyInfo'), TYPE),
              (SELECT 'FATCA' "@Id",
                      (SELECT  
                             (SELECT
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('SendingCompanyIN'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('TransmittingCountry'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('ReceivingCountry'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('MessageType'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('Warning'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('Contact'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('MessageRefId'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('ReportingPeriod'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('Timestamp'), TYPE)
                                FOR XML PATH('MessageSpec'), TYPE),
                             (SELECT ''
                                FOR XML PATH('FATCA'), TYPE)
                         FOR XML PATH('FATCA_OECD'), TYPE)
                 FOR XML PATH('Object'), TYPE)
          FOR XML PATH('Signature'))

SELECT @XML
```

This is what i have so far and it works perfect.

I've already read this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx but doesn't really help me because i need to use namespaces at the middle of xml and can't figure it out how.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` to create the XML you need. Change `SET` to a `SELECT`.

Something like this.

```sql
DECLARE @XML XML;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#',
                   'urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1' as ftc,
                   'urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes' as sfa)
SELECT @XML = (SELECT   
              (SELECT 
                     (SELECT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xmlexcc14n#' "@Algorithm"
                        FOR XML PATH('CanonicalizationMethod'), TYPE),
                     (SELECT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsigmore#rsasha256' "@Algorithm"
                        FOR XML PATH('SignatureMethod'), TYPE),
                     (SELECT '#FATCA' "@URI",
                             (SELECT 
                                     (SELECT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xmlexcc14n#' "@Algorithm"
                                       FOR XML PATH('Transform'), TYPE)
                                 FOR XML PATH('Transforms'), TYPE),
                             (SELECT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256' "@Algorithm"
                                 FOR XML PATH('DigestMethod'), TYPE),
                             (SELECT ''
                                 FOR XML PATH('DigestValue'), TYPE)
                         FOR XML PATH('Reference'), TYPE)                            
                 FOR XML PATH('SignedInfo'), TYPE),
              (SELECT ''
                 FOR XML PATH('SignatureValue'), TYPE),
              (SELECT
                     (SELECT
                            (SELECT ''
                               FOR XML PATH('X509SubjectName'), TYPE),
                            (SELECT ''
                               FOR XML PATH('X509Certificate'), TYPE)
                        FOR XML PATH('X509Data'), TYPE)
                 FOR XML PATH('KeyInfo'), TYPE),
              (SELECT 'FATCA' "@Id",
                      (SELECT  
                             (SELECT
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('sfa:SendingCompanyIN'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('sfa:TransmittingCountry'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('sfa:ReceivingCountry'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('sfa:MessageType'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('sfa:Warning'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('sfa:Contact'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('sfa:MessageRefId'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('sfa:ReportingPeriod'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT ''
                                       FOR XML PATH('sfa:Timestamp'), TYPE)
                                FOR XML PATH('ftc:MessageSpec'), TYPE),
                             (SELECT ''
                                FOR XML PATH('ftc:FATCA'), TYPE)
                         FOR XML PATH('ftc:FATCA_OECD'), TYPE)
                 FOR XML PATH('Object'), TYPE)
          FOR XML PATH('Signature'));

SELECT @XML;
```

It does not look exactly like what you have in your picture but it is the same XML semantically.

**Update:**

To avoid the bloating of namespaces in the child nodes you can build one level at a time using an XML variable and then use that variable in your main query.

Sample code:

```sql
declare @X xml;

with xmlnamespaces(default 'N2',
                   'N3' as n3,
                   'N4' as n4)
select @X = (
            select 2 as Elem2
            for xml path('n4:SubElem'), type
            );

with xmlnamespaces(default 'N1')
select 1 as Elem1,
       @X
for xml path('Root')
```

Result:

```xml
<Root xmlns="N1">
  <Elem1>1</Elem1>
  <n4:SubElem xmlns:n4="N4" xmlns:n3="N3" xmlns="N2">
    <Elem2>2</Elem2>
  </n4:SubElem>
</Root>
```

You can even create functions for your sub nodes.

```sql
create function [dbo].[GetSubElem]() returns xml
as
begin

  declare @X xml;

  with xmlnamespaces(default 'N2',
                     'N3' as n3,
                     'N4' as n4)
  select @X = (
              select 2 as Elem2
              for xml path('n4:SubElem'), type
              );

    return @x
end
```

And use it like this.

```sql
with xmlnamespaces(default 'N1')
select 1 as Elem1,
       dbo.GetSubElem()
for xml path('Root')
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael. But not entirely solve my problem because now i have all xml tags with all namespaces declared... Signature tag must have xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" and ftc:FATCA_OECD tag all the others namespaces... except the xmlns, because this one must be urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1... Thanks again..

Comment: @user2196272 I know. That is unnecessary bloating of the XML and a limitation in SQL Server when you build the XML in sub queries. But the XML is still valid. Declarations of unused namespaces should not be a problem and leaving out namespaces that you don't use, like the default namespace in the a sub-element, shouldn't either. That depends of course on what  kind of software you are using to interpret the XML but if well written it should not matter.

Comment: @user2196272 Updated answer with something that you can use to get better control over where, when and how the namespaces are added.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update... It is exactly what i was looking for.. Thanks again...